# Fill DOM element template with javascript object properties

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am a brand new member, but not a new user. I've searched everywhere for an answer to this with no luck. Here's my problem:

I am making online flashcards for school using [Flip](https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/). I made one template card and styled with CSS (specifics not shown), then that sits in a flexbox container. I then have a separate JS file where I define the flashcard details as so:

```js
var card1 = {
  type: "military"
  name: "F22",
  engine: "turbofan",
  wingspan: "44",
  speed: "1500"
};

var card2 = {
  type: "commercial"
  name: "747",
  engine: "rolls royce",
  wingspan: "211",
  speed: "570"
};
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 3px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  text-align: left;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flip-card">
    <div class="flip-card-inner">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <ul>
          <li class="name">name</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card-back">
        <ul>
          <li class="type">type</li>
          <li class="engine">engine</li>
          <li class="wingspan">wingspan</li>
          <li class="speed">speed</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is every time I add a new Javascript card details, to copy the "card template" in the HTML file, and fill it with the new card details, continuing to add cards as I go. I want to keep the details in a separate file to simplify the code and not have to copy/paste a million times. I have tried using `.clone()`, but I can't associate the JS object properties to the various HTML element classes and IDs within the template. Anyone have any tips?

Comment: Create a helper function that generators the markup you want and use innerText to set the text content of individual nodes.

Comment: @Terry thanks for the response. Sorry I come from an OOP/C# world so I'm new to the syntax of HTML and JS. How do I associate each property to the classes in the HTML card object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of creating a template is actually good. The template tag can be placed in the html file and won't be rendered.

```
<template id="card">
   <div id="container">
     <div id="name"></div>
   </div>
</template>
```

You can clone it and add it to the DOM. You have to add your card's properties manually:

```
function createCard(card) {
    const t = document.querySelector('#card')
    const clone = t.content.cloneNode(true)
    clone.querySelector("#name").innerText = card.name
    document.body.appendChild(clone)
}

createCard(card1)
```

A nicer way to do this is to put all your objects in an array and loop through them:

```
let cards = [
    {name:"F22"}, {name:"747"}
]

for(let c of cards) {
    createCard(c)
}
```

Comment: I really like this idea. I'm running into a problem though; if I put the card html inside a <template> tag, the content doesn't render. However inside a <div> tag works fine, although the template is visible now. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's the whole idea of the template. It is not rendered, it only exists so you can use `cloneNode` and get a copy of the template's content (using `template.content`). You add that copy to the DOM using `addChild()`

Comment: Awesome! I figured out I had to wrap the card block in a separate template tag rather than making it the template itself and it works like a charm. Much appreciated! 